# AwakeFromNib not getting called, cell rendering but outlets are nil

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a table view cell with a nib, all the outlets are connected properly. I am registering the cell, but the awakeFromNib is not being called. I am well deep into the app and I have registered many cells like this one, but this one is acting funny. The cell is rendered, because it comes inside the if let and when I give it `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .red`, it shows the cell on the screen, but without the content like the label or images. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess here but maybe you are registering a cell class instead of a nib?
Make sure you call this:

```
register(UINib(nibName: "MyCell",bundle: Bundle.main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "identifier")
```

and not this:

```
register(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "identifier")
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing if you already added "override func awakeFromNib()" function in your Cell class. You will have to override awakeFromNib function in Swift class.